# C++ - how to delete sub-classes in destructor

Tags: c++, class, destructor

Here is a class definition:

```
class Person {
private:
    char* name;
    int numChildren;
    Person** childrenList;
public:
    Person(char* name);
    ~Person();
};
```

In the `Person::Person()` constructor, it will set up the name of the person based on the constructor parameter, and then create `Person` object for each child, and each child may have other children.  And let's say for one case, after I run this: `Person* me = new Person("Alex");`, the following structure will be created:
[image]
ie if `me` is created, `me`'s children will also be recursively created.

But I have a trouble in the `Person::~Person()` destructor. In the destructor it should delete all dynamic objects including name and every child. Here is my attempt:

```
Person::~Person() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
        // go inside each child
    }
    delete[] this->name;
    delete[] childrenList;
}
```

But I don't know how to go inside each child, and the destructor has no parameter.

Could anyone give me some hint? Thanks!

Comment: Normally, the answer is "don't do your own memory allocation, use string and vector and smart pointers instead, which clean up automatically". Are you required (e.g. by a professor) to use new/delete? That said, if you just `delete` each child in that loop, it will call that child's destructor and set off the recursive chain you're looking for.

Comment: @parktomatomi well it's from homework and I changed it a little bit and I'm not allow to modify the class definition, so I have to use new/delete. Is there some ways to delete everything when deleting the first one?

Comment: What does your constructor look like? (Sometimes a destructor looks like the constructor "in reverse".)

Comment: You're almost there. If you declare the root Person on the stack, the destructor will be called automatically. If you declared the root Person on the heap with `new`, the destructor will be called when you `delete` it. So if you delete the first one, it calls your destructor. Then if the destructor deletes each entry in `childrenList` in that loop, it will call the destructor for each child, on and on until the only pointers left are NULL or the list is empty.

Comment: @parktomatomi could you explain more about when the children destructor will be called? Do you mean that if I just `delete childrenList`, each children destructor will be called?

Comment: @JaMiT the constructor is briefly like this: 1. set up name 2. for each item in `childrenList` create a new `Person` object then it will call constructor itself and recursively build the whole structure. Sorry that I cannot post the original work online.

Comment: How the object created and inserted into the ChildrenList is important?
Can you add some code snippets of it?

Comment: @keanehui1 Do you see how the accepted answer is your constructor "in reverse"? The order of the steps is reversed, and the actions taken are inverted. 1. For each item in `childrenList` uncreate the `Person` object. 2. Unset up `name`.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes I found that the constructor uses `new` to trigger the sub-constructor, and the destructor uses `delete` to trigger the sub-destructor so that they are recursive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `delete` each child before you `delete[] childrenlist` :

```
Person::~Person()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
        delete childrenList[i];
    }
    delete[] childrenList;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when using a double poiner like `Person** childrenList`, you have to do this to allocate and delete it:

```
    unsigned len1 = 100;
    unsigned len2 = 100;

    //  childrenList is a pointer to a an array of pointers
    Person** childrenList = nullptr;

    // create an array with UNALLOCATED Person pointers, note the "*"
    childrenList = new  Person*[len1];          

    // allocate all the pointers in the the array
    for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < len1; i1++)
        childrenList[i1] = new Person;


    // delete all the pointer in the array
    for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < len1; i1++)
        if (childrenList[i1])
            delete childrenList[i1];        

    // delete the array itself
    delete[] childrenList;
```

you could put this in your destructor:

```
Person::~Person()
{
// delete all the pointer in the array
        for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < len1; i1++)
            if (childrenList[i1])
                delete childrenList[i1];        

        // delete the list itself
        delete[] childrenList;

}
```

But this whole thing would be done easier with a "2d" std::vector:

```
vec<vec<Person>> childrenList;
```

Such a 2d vector has its own syntax, but it is easier and less error prone than "bare" pointers/arrays.-
PS: I have NOT tried to compile or run this example.